# Dropped external drive, any chance of recovering data?

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery

My WD 1TB Drive fell off from my bed and no longer works. It makes a steady ringing sound.
I have tried testing it with Data Lifeguard Tool, but that shows my drive has 0GB capacity. What else can I try?

I want to repair it myself because there are so many important files in there and I do not want to give it to someone to repair.

What should I do?

Firmware Revision: 1003
Device serial Number: WX81E81ADLP3

Comment: Do you have a cleanroom available? If not, let the file rescue to professionals.

Comment: That’s some really bad luck. Not only are your files probably gone, but it’s [not even under warranty anymore](http://websupport.wdc.com/warranty/warrantycheck2.asp?req=184138&rnd=06653253). ◉︵◉     Unfortunately I know how you feel. I once lost an 850MB file with some files I really wanted when it slipped off of a 2-inch block I put it on to keep it near an open computer. I also lost a 160GB drive when the stupid SATA-to-USB adapter literally burned the drive’s circuit board. Fortunately this one had no irreplaceable files, but still…

Comment: Oh, and “ringing” isn’t very meaningful in this context, so if you can record a clip of it and post it to SoundCloud or Chirbit, then we can take a listen and determine just how bad it is.

Comment: _I want to repair it myself because there are so many important files in there_ Might as well crush it then. Hair, dust particles and lint are thicker than the distance between the heads and the platters while in operation. Depending on the ringing, you might have gotten unlucky and broke one of the heads loose or bent the supporting blade so the head's dragging. This is beyond DIY to repair.

Comment: Have you tried restoring important files from backups you made earlier?

Comment: If it's an external drive the first step would be to disassemble the external housing and see if anything has come loose or has gotten bent in a way that you can correct.  But the drive itself is generally impossible for a mere mortal to disassemble (or even to remove the external electronics) and hope to put back together again.  This is why we make backups (and don't store hard drives on the bed).

Comment: If it is the kind of ringing I am thinking your not doing it any good to spin it up at all. it could be the platters rubbing on something. There is a specific thing that the failure testing reported the platters motor getting off axiel (I didnt catch the terms) where the shaft and platter assembly get knocked out of straight.

Answer (score 4):

Both of the people here have the correct answer, Your hard drive ringing sound means 1 of the piece in the hard drive has broken or mal-functioned one way or another, which is VERY bad for you. Taking it to a reputable place like Steven Haung has mentioned can be VERY VERY pricy, because maintaining a clean room is indeed not a cheap thing. I've heard some places charging 5-10 thousand to repair hard drives in my area.

Ways to avoid this from happening

1. Don't place Hard Drive on Bed. :)
2. Always keep backups of important information on a flash drive, Network Drives on the internet, stored in email account if you have the room, or where ever.
3. Or just make a clone of the data on another hard drive.

If the value of the items on this drive are worth the cost of repairing it, i would do it, if they are not, cut your losses and be more careful in the future.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't try to fix it yourself, take it to a reputable place to have it repaired. Hard drives are very delicate in the inside.